# Excel data validation not able to make indirect to work with if function, along with indirect I am trying to use row function

Tags: excel

Below formula working fine with fixed value to indirect function "$B$2"

```
=IF(INDIRECT("$B$2")="",SubBusinessList,INDEX(SubBusinessColumn,MATCH($B$2,AppIdsColumn,0)))
```

But if I use `ROW()` instead of 2 in "$B$2" its not working.
Below formula is not working.

```
=IF(INDIRECT("$B$"&ROW())="",SubBusinessList,INDEX(SubBusinessColumn,MATCH($B$2,AppIdsColumn,0)))
```

Where I am doing wrong any suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using this in data validation formula?

Comment: Yes @GowthamShiva

Comment: Getting any error? or just no result? would like to see your data too

Comment: Any suggestions @GowthamShiva

Comment: @GowthamShiva After adding ROW() function while saving it shows warning "The source currently evaluated to an error. Do you want to continue?"